# MySQL: Update second table with trigger and IF statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a trigger which sets selectoin allow to 1 when main state is updated to 3. However I can't get the query to work correctly. So far I have:

```
create table main
(main_id varchar(30) primary key,
name varchar(30) null,
state int null,
update_timestamp timestamp null);

create table selection 
(id varchar(30) primary key,
allow varchar(30) null,
last_update_timestamp timestamp null);

//
create trigger upd_selectoin 
before update on main 
for each row 
     IF new.state = 3 
     THEN 
   UPDATE selection s
    JOIN main m 
      ON m.main_id = s.id
     SET s.allow = 1
   WHERE s.id = NEW.main_id;
  END IF;
END;
//

insert into main values (1,'row1',1,null);
insert into main values (2,'row2',0,null);

insert into selection values (1,null,null);
insert into selection values (2,null,null);
```

Error message:

> Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that      corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '//

Comment: `Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that      corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two problems with the syntax:

1. You meant to use `DELIMITER //`
2. You forgot `BEGIN`

The correct definition might look like

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER upd_selectoin 
BEFORE UPDATE ON main 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF NEW.state = 3 THEN 
    UPDATE selection s JOIN main m 
        ON m.main_id = s.id
       SET s.allow = 1
     WHERE s.id = NEW.main_id; 
  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e849f/1)** demo

---

Now in your case

1. You probably want to use `AFTER` event instead of `BEFORE` to make sure that update in `main` has been made successfully before you make any updates to `selection`.
2. Also there is no point in JOINing `selection` with `main` since you already know `main_id`.
3. You can utilize `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to make sure that a row in `selection` will exist even if it wasn't before
4. Looking at the `selection` schema you probably meant to assign a timestamp during that update

That being said a more succinct version of your trigger might look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_selection 
AFTER UPDATE ON main 
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO selection (id, allow, last_update_timestamp)
  VALUES (NEW.main_id, IF(NEW.state = 3, 1, NULL), NOW())
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE allow = VALUES(allow), 
                          last_update_timestamp = VALUES(last_update_timestamp);
```

This version of a trigger doesn't even need `DELIMITER` and `BEGIN ... END` block because it contains only one statement.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6def/1)** demo

Comment: Hi pererm, thanks that's perfect, I understand what is happening now :)